# How can I stop using App Registration secrets and use Managed Identities in Microsoft Identity platform?

Tags: c#, azure, authentication, identity, azure-managed-identity

We have been getting complaints from clients because we use Microsoft Identity in Azure Web Apps, and we use App Registration with secrets, but when they expire, the users are unable to log into the applications until we generate new secrets and replace the configuration.
I started using Managed Identity for some resources, but can't figure out how or if it is possible to use it to authorize the users in the application.
Right now we just put this on top of a controller method, and we get a popup requesting permissions from the user if it is the first time.

```
[AuthorizeForScopes(Scopes = new[] { "User.Read", "Calendars.ReadWrite" })]
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
```

This is the configuration

```
services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
  .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))
  .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi()
  .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
```

```
{
  "AzureAd": {
    "TenantId": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "xxxx.xxxx",
    "ClientId": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
    "SignedOutCallbackPath ": "/signout-callback-oidc",
    "ClientSecret": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  }
}
```

I thought it would be as easy as assigning the Managed Identity Service Principal in the App Registration instead of the secret or certificate, but at least in the Azure Portal, there is no way to do this.
I searched in Azure portal, the search engines and the AI bots. No one seems to address this.

Your help is greatly appreciated.

JR